# Sending e-mail with inline images using JavaMail API

Tags: java, email, attachment

I am using the following code to send a email along with the image and it is working perfectly. When I send the image, it is getting displayed in the body instead of getting attached in the e-mail. So, that I can easily download that image from the attachment.

Is there any way to add image in the attachment image in the e-mail instead of the image present in body?

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendInlineImagesInEmail
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "destinationemail@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "fromemail@gmail.com";
        final String username = "manishaspatil"; //change accordingly
        final String password = "******"; //change accordingly

        // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
        String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            // This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
                "/home/manisha/javamail-mini-logo.png");

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

            // add image to the multipart
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, instead of adding image in the body is there any way to attach that image in the mail??

Comment: Do you you want your image just as an attachment?

Comment: yes, so that i can easily download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an image as attachment , am using [`FileDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html).

```
    // Set a file as an attachment
    public static void setFileAsAttachment(Message msg, String filename)
             throws MessagingException {

        // Create and fill first part
        MimeBodyPart p1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        p1.setText("This is part one of a test multipart e-mail." +
                    "The second part is file as an attachment");

        // Create second part
        MimeBodyPart p2 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Put a file in the second part
        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(filename);
        p2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        p2.setFileName(fds.getName());

        // Create the Multipart.  Add BodyParts to it.
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(p1);
        mp.addBodyPart(p2);

        // Set Multipart as the message's content
        msg.setContent(mp);
    }
```

And pass your image-path,

```
setFileAsAttachment(msg, "<path here>");
```